# Linux service to set /proc/$pid/oom_score_adj of new processes?

Tags: linux, out-of-memory

Is there any available software which can be used to set the `/proc/<pid>/oom_score_adj` of processes after they're created, based upon the executable name and the user/group?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8255487/512360 gives an answer how you can be notified on "events in `/proc`" (including process creation). To my knowledge, there's not ready-made daemon that'll then try post-event to change the OOM score adjustment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created an utility that does it solely based on the executable name, in addition to setting the CPU and I/O priority: https://git.janouch.name/p/desktop-tools/src/branch/master/priod.c

It can be installed with the parent package as per its README. Just copy the example configuration to */etc/priod.conf*, change it according to your needs and enable the systemd unit, and it should work. Note that it goes through already existing processes on startup, too.

I hope it will help someone, at least as an example.

Comment: 404 as of July 2018.

Comment: Link corrected.